# Не совпадает результат - С++

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
bool is_it_max(int* arr, int a,int size){
    int i = 0,buf = a;
    while(i < size){
        if(a < arr[i] ){
            a = arr[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(buf == a){
        return true;
    } else return false;
}
int main() {
    //freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    //freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
    int n = 0;
    int v = 1, sum = 0;
    cin>>n;
    int i =0;
    int* arr = new int[n];
    while(i < n){
        cin >> arr[i];
        i++;
    }
    cout << sum;
    for(int j = 0; j < n;j++){
        if(is_it_max(arr,arr[j],n)){
            sum+=(arr[j]*v);
            v-=v;
            arr[j] = 0;
        } else arr[j] = 0;
        v++;
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Входные данные:

> 5
>
> 73 31 96 24 46

Желаемый результат - 380 но у меня выводит 0380 , как избавиться от этого нуля перед числом, пытался взять остаток от деления этого числа на 1000, выводит то же самое

решаю задачу по [этой](http://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=39) ссылке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну уберите первый вывод

```
 cout << sum;
```

в тот момент, когда `sum` равно 0, в чем проблемы?...

Comment: Спасибо, сидел пол часа не мог понять в чем проблема)